# How to find to see if a set exists in a set of sets

Tags: c++

It's relatively hard to explain.

So for example, if I have a set a that is {(0,0,0), (0,1,0), (0, 0, 1)} and set b is {((0,0,0), (0,1,0), (0, 0, 1)), ((0,0,0), (0,1,0), (0, 0, 2), ...), ...}.

What function would allow me to see if set a exists in set b? I also want to make sure that the function returns false when set b has ((0,0,0), (0,1,0), (0, 0, 1), (0,0,2)) and not the exact set((0,0,0), (0,1,0), (0, 0, 1)).

Thank you so much.

I tried the function includes(b.begin(), b.end(), a.begin(), a.end()), but it does not work because it only checks if there is a subset.

Example code that shows this underneath.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  set <tuple<int, int, int>> coord;
  set <tuple<int, int, int>> testcoord0;
  set <tuple<int, int, int>> testcoord1;
  set <tuple<int, int, int>> total_set;
  tuple <int, int, int> tuple0 = make_tuple(0, 0, 0);
  tuple <int, int, int> tuple1 = make_tuple(0, 1, 0);
  tuple <int, int, int> tuple2 = make_tuple(0, 0, 1);
  tuple <int, int, int> tuple3 = make_tuple(0, 0, 2);
  tuple <int, int, int> tuple4 = make_tuple(0, 2, 0);
  tuple <int, int, int> tuple5 = make_tuple(2, 0, 0);

  coord.insert(tuple0);
  coord.insert(tuple1);
  coord.insert(tuple2);
  testcoord0.insert(tuple0);
  testcoord0.insert(tuple1);
  testcoord0.insert(tuple2);
  testcoord0.insert(tuple3);
  total_set.insert(testcoord0.begin(), testcoord0.end());
  testcoord1.insert(tuple3);
  testcoord1.insert(tuple4);
  testcoord1.insert(tuple5);
  total_set.insert(testcoord1.begin(), testcoord1.end());

  
  if (includes(total_set.begin(), total_set.end(), coord.begin(), coord.end())) {
        cout<< "it does exists" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout<< "it does not exists" << endl;
    }
  
}
```

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` -- Get rid of this header.

Comment: Your second paragraph appears to describe the plain, garden-variety, `==` operator. If `==` operator is not what you're looking for, you need to explain, precisely, and concisely, what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: In your example, set b can't contain set a since b doesn't contain sets. It can contain elements that compares equal to those stored in set a though.

Comment: [`std::set::contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/contains) or if you can't use C++20, [`std::set::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/count).  Or [`std::set::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) if you need to access the set if it is contained.  The text of your question doesn't match the code in your question though, so that may change depending on which version you're actually interested in.

Comment: I think you want [std::set::contains](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/contains): `bool const hasA = b.contains(a);`

Comment: In your code, `total_set` is not a "set of sets". It's a set of tuples (just like, say, `coord`), initialized to a union of `testcoord0` and `testcoord1`. In light of this, what exactly do you want to test for?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).